# Importing in Python

Tags: python, import

In Python 2.5, I import modules by changing environment variables.  It works, but using site-packages does not.  Is there another way to import modules in directories other than C:\Python25 ?

Comment: What does "using site-packages does not" mean?  What code are you  using?  What error are you getting?  What -- specifically -- is happening?

Comment: @S.Lott: 39 questions and you haven't get used to him yet?

Comment: @SilentGhost: My default assumption is that people -- eventually -- learn something.  Statistically, this appears to be a case where learning does not appear to be happening.

Comment: @S.Lott: if you haven't noticed, there is a group of users that have 0 answers, but dozens of poorly-worded questions. My feeling is that they use this community to do their jobs. Dishonesty is always more probable than limited mental abilities, that's what Heinlein taught me ;)

Comment: @SilentGhost:  Just responding to the dishonesty comment.  The stuff is hard if you don't know what you are doing.  I often find that authors will leave out very basic things in tutorials assuming that the base knowledge is a given.  I think that leads to a lot of overly simplified poorly represented questions.  Also, I highly recommend Heinlein to anyone who can read.

Comment: @SilentGhost http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/the-hunting-of-the-snark/

Answer (score 7):

On way is with [**`PYTHONPATH`**](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. Other one is to add path to [**`sys.path`**](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) either directly by **`sys.path.append(path)`** or by defining **`.pth`** files and add them to with [**`site.addsitedir(dirWithPths)`**](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html#site.addsitedir). Path files (`.pth`) are simple text files with a path in each line. Every `.pth` file in `dirWithPths` will be read.

Comment: its not working . site.addsitedir(dirWithPths) is returning None
Can you help me?

Comment: ¿What do you expect it to return? It just adds paths to sys.path.

Comment: Looks a .pth file is good enough to let python search for the module. No need to use `site.addsitedir(dirWithPths)`, which is only necessary if you want to put the .pth file in some non-default importing directory that python is looking into.

Answer (score 4):

Append the location to the module to `sys.path`.

Edit: (to counter the post below ;-) )
`os.path` does something completely different. You need to use `sys.path`.

```
sys.path.append("/home/me/local/modules")
```

Comment: os.path.append doesn't do anything completely different except raising AttributeError

Comment: not sure what I said to offend you there, but there was no ill intent.

Comment: probably the part where you said "So os.path.append might not generate an error" which is untrue since os.path does not have an append method or attribute, resulting in an AttributeError as SilentGhost said

Comment: omg. I was so wondering about being offensive, I missed the 'being stupid' part. Sorry about that. It was a very poor formulated comment, so I'll just remove it so it'll cause no further harm :-)

Answer (score 4):

Directories added to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable are searched after `site-packages`, so if you have a module in `site-packages` with the same name as the module you want from your `PYTHONPATH`, the `site-packages` version will win. Also, you may need to restart your interpreter and the shell that launched it for the change to the environment variable to take effect.

If you want to add a directory to the search path at run time, without restarting your program, add the directory to `sys.path`. For example:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(newpath)
```

If you want your new directory to be searched before `site-packages`, put the directory at the front of the list, like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, newpath)
```

Answer (score -1):

`sys.path` is a list to which you can append custom paths to search like this:

```
sys.path.append("/home/foo")
```

Comment: Fixed - the amazing thing was that I typed "os.path" twice and didn't notice.