# How to add a Python import path using a .pth file

Tags: python, python-import

If I put a *.pth file in site-packages it's giving an `ImportError`.
I'm not getting how to import by creating a *.pth file.

*(Refers to [importing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697281/importing-in-python))*

Comment: You should add a link to the original question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697281/importing-in-python

Comment: -1: You should provide (1) code, (2) the actual error message, (3) the .pth file you're using.

Answer (score 43):

If you put a `.pth` file in the `site-packages` directory containing a path, python searches this path for imports. So I have a `sth.pth` file there that simply contains:

```
K:\Source\Python\lib
```

In that directory there are some normal Python modules:

```
logger.py
fstools.py
...
```

This allows to directly import these modules from other scripts:

```
import logger

log = logger.Log()
...
```

Comment: Short and simple... :-)

Comment: But where do you put the sth.pth file? when python is installed in C:\python27 ?

Comment: thank you, i have used `import sys`; `sys.path.append(path)` for some time now. this works

Answer (score 27):

```
/tmp/$ mkdir test; cd test
/tmp/test/$ mkdir foo; mkdir bar
/tmp/test/$ echo -e "foo\nbar" > foobar.pth
/tmp/test/$ cd ..
/tmp/$ python
Python 2.6 (r26:66714, Feb  3 2009, 20:52:03)
[GCC 4.3.2 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 141291]] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site, sys
>>> site.addsitedir('test')
>>> sys.path[-3:]
['/tmp/test', '/tmp/test/foo', '/tmp/test/bar']
```

Comment: please include a short description of what you're doing