# __init__.py usage for directories in Python

Tags: python

I use `__init__.py` in my project with the following structure :

```
project\
    project.py
    cfg.py
    __init__.py

    database\
       data.py
       __init__.py

    test\
       test_project.py
       __init__.py
```

All is OK when I need to see database\ modules in project.py with

```
from database.data import *
```

But if I need to have some test code inside the test_project.py, how to 'see' the database\ modules ?

Comment: Don't you also need to `import project` in test_project.py?

Comment: Yes I need too but i would simplify my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 options:

- use relative imports (`from .. import database.data`). I wouldn't recommend that one.
- append paths to `sys.path` in your code.
- use `addsitedir()` and `.pth` files. [Here is how.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700375/how-to-add-a-python-import-path-using-a-pth-file)

Comment: OK...I choose to add paths in sys.path

Answer (score 2):

[Relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

```
from .. import database.data
```

Comment: Relative imports are officially discouraged.

Comment: I have a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error (in Python 2.71)

Answer (score 2):

If you run a script from the directory that contains `project\`, you can simply do `from project.database.data import *`, in `test_project.py`.

This is generally a good idea, because [relative imports are officially discouraged](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Relative imports for intra-package
>   imports are highly discouraged. Always
>   use the absolute package path for all
>   imports. Even now that PEP 328 [7] is
>   fully implemented in Python 2.5, its
>   style of explicit relative imports is
>   actively discouraged; absolute imports
>   are more portable and usually more
>   readable.

Absolute imports like the one given above are encouraged.

Comment: I have no pb to run test_project.py from project\ but I would run it from project\test\