# Difference between setup.py install and setup.py develop

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to improve my workflow when developing python modules and have a rather basic question.

What exactly happens when choosing either option. To my knowledge *develop* leaves the files in place so I can modify them and play around with the package whereas *install* copies them in the *site-packages* folder of my python installation. How is the package linked to my python installation when using the *develop* option.

Comment: "Develp" adds in your site a python path file (.pth) file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700375/how-to-add-a-python-import-path-using-a-pth-file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`develop` creates an `.egg-link` file in the `site-packages` directory, which points back to the location of the project files. The same path is also added to the `easy-install.pth` file in the same location. Uninstalling with `setup.py develop -u` removes that link file again.

Do note that any `install_requires` dependencies not yet present are also installed, as regular eggs (they are `easy_install`-ed). Those dependencies are not uninstalled when uninstalling the development egg.