# What does `pipenv install -e .` do and how to use it?

Tags: python, pipenv

`pipenv` help documentation writes:

> Install a local setup.py into your virtual environment/Pipfile:
>
> $ pipenv install -e .

Can someone further elaborate when and how to use the command `pipenv install -e .`  in relation to `setup.py`?

According to `pipenv`, `-e .` refers to [editable dependencies](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/#editable-dependencies-e-g-e). However, I am unable to understand the given explanation. Can someone explain this?

**Edit:**
For example, after I had created a simple distro package call `mypkg` in my `--user` directory in `pip`, i.e.`~/mypkg`, using commands:

```
$ pipenv shell
(mypkg-x985xH5M) $ python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
(mypkg-x985xH5M) $ twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

and `/mypkg` and has the following file structure:

```
/mypkg
  |_ LICENSE
  |_ README.md
  |_ setup.py
  |_ /mypkg
  |    |_ __init__.py
  |    |_ mypkg.py
  |_ /dist
  |    |_ mypkg-0.0.1rc1.tar.gz
  |    |_ mypkg-0.0.1rc1-py3-none-any.whl
  |_ /build
  |    |_ /bdist.linux-x86_64
  |    |_ /lib
  |         |_ /mypkg
  |              |_ __init__.py
  |              |_ mypkg.py
  |_ /mypkg.egg-info
       |_ dependency_links.txt
       |_ entry_points.txt
       |_ PKG-INFO
       |_ SOURCES.txt
       |_ top_level.txt
```

what does the command `$ pipenv install -e .` do?

Comment: Haven't used pipenv specifically, but I'd imagine it's identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35064426/when-would-be-e-editable-option-useful-with-pip-install

Comment: @user3483203: it is absolutely identical.

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks for the link. In addition I found documentation on [pip install](https://pip-python3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git) helpful, especially on VCS.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Normally, `pip` (driving `setup.py` or another [PEP 518 compliant build tool](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/)) will build and *install* a Python project, into the Python `site-packages` location. `.py` and `.pyc` files are copied over in this process.

This means that if you have a local copy of the project on disk, you can't just edit the `.py` source files and see the changes reflected in projects that load those same files from `site-packages`.

The `-e` switch builds, then installs a pointer file in `site-packages` that automatically adds the location of the project to Python's module search path. Now loading the modules will load them from the on-disk location, not from `site-packages`, and changes to the files will show up every time you run a Python project that uses it. See [Python setup.py develop vs install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048732/python-setup-py-develop-vs-install) and [Difference between setup.py install and setup.py develop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339183/difference-between-setup-py-install-and-setup-py-develop)

`.` just tells `pip` / `pipenv` to take the current working directory as the location of the project to build (`setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` file with `[build-system]` section should exist in that directory).

For your example, running `pip install -e .` in `~/mypkg`, it means `python3 setup.py develop` will be run, adding a `.egg-link` file in the `site-packages` directory of the Python 3 virtualenv that Pipenv is maintaining. In the same `site-packages` directory is a `easy-install.pth` file that is updated to add the full path of the `~/mypkg` directory. All this means that `import mypkg` in Python will import the code directly from the `~/mypkg/mypkg` package, and any changes you make to the `.py` files there are going to be directly available.

Comment: I have elaborated on my question (see Edit). Can you simplify your explanation to help me understand what is going on during `pipenv install -e .`? Pardon my inability to connect your explanation to my question. Thank u.

Comment: `pipenv install -e .` will add dependencies from setup.py (`install_requires`) to `Pipfile.lock` and install these dependencies into the current virtual environment. The `-e`  flag will install the project in editable mode (it will not copy project files to site-packages)

Comment: Yes, pipenv is just a wrapper around pip in this case, one that records direct and indirect dependencies as a hierarchy and helps recreate the same environment elsewhere given the same lock file.