# Python pyramid setup.py install

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a website host on google cloud engine. I use Python Pyramid framework and jinja2.

When I update profile image, image was upload successfull but image is not show .

If i run sudo python3.6 setup.py install and restart web server again. The profile image will be show .

PS : I use mod_wsgi and apache2, not use virtual env

I don't know why, anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If i use

$sudo python3.6 setup.py develop

then upload image was work fine for me.

What the difference between setup.py install and setup.py develop

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339183/difference-between-setup-py-install-and-setup-py-develop)