# Python how to make a function visible for other python modules

Tags: python, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697281/importing-in-python)

I have a couple of functions and I want to make them visible as library functions to be able to call them from other projects. I want to have them in a separate directory from common python libraries. How I should arrange my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this in project where you want import your functions:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:\\myprojects\\MyProjDir\\')

from MyModule import MyClass
```

Note, that file with name `__init__.py` must be placed in `MyProjDir`.
Otherwise Python will not scan this directory. Contents of `__init__.py` can be left blank.

**Docs:**

1. [Modifying Python’s Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path)
2. [The Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: Avoid manipulations of sys.path in your code. This makes it fragile, and not reusable on other systems.

Comment: I would appreciate if you explain more solid methods. (`virtualenv`?)

Comment: Use setuptools (based on distutils). It will manage `.pth` files for you, by using commands such as `develop` to set up develop mode. You can then also deploy distributions from the same code base.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to make a package containing your code. A quick introduction can be found here: http://guide.python-distribute.org/introduction.html There are different options how to manage your package in relation to other projects. I would propose to use setuptools to create a distributable package. If you want to isolate your development from the default python installation, have a look at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

You must save this function in some my file, and from other file or module use import.

Comment: How other scripts will find this one?

Comment: See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm

Answer (score 0):

Define these functions in a seperate file and use import to refer them. A helpful link (modules in python): http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html